# Passing network credential to System.Net.NetworkCredential

Tags: powershell, smtpclient

How to pass the network credentials of machine (domain\machine$) to send the mails.

I have below script but its not accepting domain\Machine$, and its looking for pwd as well. Machine accounts are with network credentials and don't have pwd.

```
$smtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
$smtpClient.Host = "smtpx-dc1.msn.com"
$smtpClient.Port = 25029
$smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $false
$smtpClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("dc\AServer$")
$smtpClient.EnableSsl = $true
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.From = "abc@abc.com"
$message.To.Add("abc@abc.com")
$message.Subject = "Test from Aserver"
$message.Body = "Is this working?"
$smtpClient.Send($message)
```

Comment: Can you run the script as the machine account, and set UseDefaultCredentials = true?

Answer (score 0):

thank you Maxwellb...
here is how it works

```
$smtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
$smtpClient.Host = "smtpx-dc1.msn.com"
$smtpClient.Port = 25029
$smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$smtpClient.EnableSsl = $false
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.From = "abc@abc.com"
$message.To.Add("abc@abc.com")
$message.Subject = "Test from Aserver"
$message.Body = "Is this working?"
$smtpClient.Send($message)
```

Comment: This one is failing on a specific vm with below message. "Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was notauthenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated""